# Watch for newly created files from command line

Tags: windows, file, directory, watch

I was wondering if there is any way e.g. program or code, that can monitor for new files created within a folder or not?

Comment: In which language/OS ? In Java, you've got the Apache Commons FileSystemAlterationMonitor. For command line, you have [inotify](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478) on Linux that monitors file system events. You can google for it

Comment: Windows systems, I have very little programming knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible but it works slightly different on different operating systems.

For example https://github.com/guard/guard implements this for all the mainstream systems so you can check its source code.

For Windows notifications see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(VS.85).aspx.

For Mac OS X notifications see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

For Linux see http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rml/inotify/README.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am on Windows, and can't install python :(